# How old is my bike

Tags: identify-this-bike, cruiser

I have a murray monterey green ladies beach cruiser with the following id: MOP0295856 can anyone tell me how old it is? Vintage?

Comment: You should include pictures. Note that Murray is a [tag:bso] brand.

Answer (score 1):

It dates from 1958, based on [this guy's information](https://thecabe.com/forum/threads/murray-serial-number-project.7014/)

Comment: Sorry for terribly-short answer, but there's not a lot to say.  Perhaps if there were clear and well lit photos we could say more.